# How do I convert strings in a column into numbers which I can use later, in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset consisting of 382 rows and 4 columns. I need to convert all the names in to numbers. The names do repeat here and there, so I can't just randomly give numbers.
So, I made a dictionary of the names and the corresponding values. But now, I am not able to change the values in the column.
This is how I tried to add the values to the column:

```
test_df.replace(to_replace = d_loc,value = None, regex = True, inplace = True)
print(test_df)
```

but test_df just gives me the same dataframe, without any modifications.
What should I use? I have over 100 unique names, so I cannot mannually rename them.

Comment: This seems like it's just [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)?

Answer (score 0):

[df.applymap()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) works on each item in a dataframe:

```
test_df.applymap(lambda x: dict_to_replace[x])
```

Comment: `test_df.applymap(d.get)` is slightly cleaner